# Mapbox GL JS find closest address to clicked point

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am trying to make a web app where the user can click a point and I can get the closest address to the point. [This example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/queryrenderedfeatures/) from the documentation looks pretty close to what I want to do, except it the `queryRenderedFeatures` call doesn't seem to return the physical address of any features. What is the best way to get the physical address from a clicked point?

Here is my code:

```js
  map.on("click", (e) => {
    const features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);
    const displayProperties = [
      "type",
      "properties",
      "id",
      "layer",
      "source",
      "sourceLayer",
      "state",
    ];
    const displayFeatures = features.map((feat) => {
      const displayFeat = {};
      displayProperties.forEach((prop) => {
        displayFeat[prop] = feat[prop];
      });
      return displayFeat;
    });
    console.log(displayFeatures);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term for finding the nearest address to a point is "reverse geocoding". You could use [Mapbox's API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#reverse-geocoding) for this, but there are many others, too.

There is no need to use `queryRenderedFeatures` here.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the street address from the `queryRenderedFeatures` function. However, you can get the coordinates of the point clicked:

```js
map.on("click", (e) => {
    mapClickFn(e.lngLat);
});
```

From these coordinates, you need to get a street address. This is called "reverse geocoding" and can be done using the [Mapbox API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/geocoding/#reverse-geocoding):

```js
function mapClickFn(coordinates) {
    const url =
      "https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" +
      coordinates.lng +
      "," +
      coordinates.lat +
      ".json?access_token=" +
      YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN +
      "&types=address";
    $.get(url, function (data) {
      if (data.features.length > 0) {
        const address = data.features[0].place_name;
        console.log(address);
      } else {
        console.log("No address found");
      }
    });
}
```